# How to split a string in multiple elements with LinqToXml?

Tags: c#, string, split, linq-to-xml

I got an element in a xml file looking like that:

```
<Adresse>15 rue de la tour montparnasse 75000 PARIS</Adresse>
```

From Now i only read the full adress but i need to separate the adresse's elements...

```
string FullAdress = XmlFile.Element("Adresse").Value;   

(FullAdress="15 rue de la tour montparnasse \n75000 PARIS")
```

I want separate in 3 elements:

```
string street="15 rue de la tour montparnasse" 
string ZIP="75000"
string City="PARIS"
```

How can i do that with LinqToXml ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ to XML when having neither input nor output that is XML?

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention that the string come from a xml file...

Answer (score 0):

I've exracted the data you want with:

```
var val = (from adresse in XmlFile.Elements("Adresse")
   let split = adresse.Value.Split(new[] { ' ' })
   let zip = split[split.Length - 2]
   let city = split[split.Length - 1]
   let street = string.Join(" ", split.Except(new[] { zip, city }))
   select new
   {
      Street = street,
      ZIP = zip,
      City = city
   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But you have to be carefully. This code doesn't do any verification of the data.

Comment: I need the code to be generic and work with several adresses which are different.But i think it's possible to isolate the street from the rest by using the separator "\n" and split the city and Zip where there is a 'space'...but my knowledge with Xml are very poor...